# Comma before main verb

Tags: grammar

**I saw her crying, helped me understand the matter"**

As i know comma before main verb is grammatically wrong, isn't **helped**
main verb here?

Comment: The sentence as quoted is both ungrammatical and the meaning isn't clear.  What is the exact source.  Have you quoted it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

No, "helped" is not the "main verb"--this is not a grammatically correct sentence so we cannot discuss "main verbs." I will show three different ways you can write the same thing, and discuss whether or not we need commas and why/why not.

**First Method**

I think you want to say:

> 1. I saw her crying. That helped me understand the matter.

You don't need a comma at all when it is written like this; it's two sentences.

**Second Method**

Another way of writing the same thing is:

> 2. When I saw her crying, I understood the matter.

Here a comma is needed, but not in front of a "main verb." The main verb of this sentence is "understood."

"When I saw her crying" is a dependent phrase that cannot stand alone. In my opinion, you need a comma after it. However, opinions differ. I went to school at a time when more commas were used, so listen to today's teachers.

The main part of the sentence is:

> I understood the matter.

I ask, "When did you understand the matter?" You reply:

> When I saw her crying.

But when writing that is not a complete sentence. You place a comma after it, then add the main sentence as shown.

**Third Method**

A third way of writing the same thing is:

> 3. To see her crying helped me understand the matter.

This sentence does not need a comma. "To see her crying" is the subject; it is the thing that helped you. The thing you were helped with is "understand the matter."

Thus, you have three verbs in that sentence but you don't need a single comma because the first and third verbs (see, understand) are part of a clause or phrase. "Helped" is the main verb.